# Direct query iteration VS fetch() or fun() and iteration

Tags: google-app-engine, loops, iteration

What would be more efficient or convenient?

1.- [fetch()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass?hl=en#Query_fetch) and then iterate:

```
query = MyEntity.all()
list = query.run()
for x in list:
    # do something...
```

2.- [run()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass?hl=en#Query_run) and then iterate:

```
query = MyEntity.all()
list = query.run()
for x in list:
    # do something...
```

3.- Directly iterate over the query:

```
query = MyEntity.all()
for x in query:
    # do something...
```

Answer (score 2):

From the source code of _BaseQuery which is direct superclass of Model:

```
def run(self, **kwargs):
    """Iterator for this query.

    If you know the number of results you need, use run(limit=...) instead,
    or use a GQL query with a LIMIT clause. It's more efficient. If you want
    all results use run(batch_size=<large number>).

def fetch(self, limit, offset=0, **kwargs):
    """Return a list of items selected using SQL-like limit and offset.

    Always use run(limit=...) instead of fetch() when iterating over a query.
```

Fetch is probably more useful if you have a good idea how many entities you will get, and your likley to want to prefetch reference properties or do puts of multiple entities at the same time.

If you just iterate without fetch or run, then the default batch size is possibly less than optimal and so you will have more round trips increasing latency.

Note you should also consider using ndb rather than db it gives you a few other options like easier async operations, plus is it has query.map() and query.map_async().